# SCOPE_IDENTITY, MERGE, ENTITY FRAMEWORK 6.1, COMPLEX TYPE -- RETURN TYPE

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

If I have a procedure that uses the Merge Function (Upsert) (using EF 6.1, Sql Server 2012)

Is there a difference in how `Entity Framework 6.1` would treat the `Complex Type Return Type` from using either below inside the Sql Server Procedure(After Mapping To Entity Framework):?

A:

```
--This is without declaring a output parameter
--Return Scope
 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As Id;
```

B:

```
--With Output parameter
 @new_identity    INT    OUTPUT
 SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 SELECT @new_identity AS Id
```

Updated Question Rev#1

Comment: Does this question have to do anything with EF? Sounds like a T-SQL question to me, and an unclear one.

Comment: The main difference I see is that your A example will select out a single row set with SCOPE_IDENTITY() as a numeric(38,0). Your output parameter is coming out as an int which I believe is too small to cope? e.g. you should declare as numeric... How EF treats it, i'm unsure.